# Is there a software that has implemented forces of BSE calculations for solids?

Tags: density-functional-theory, software-recommendations, td-dft, gw-bse

I'd like to investigate the structural relaxations of the excited state for periodic systems. It seems BSE is a practical method that has already been implemented in many codes for static calculations.

**I'm wondering if there's any code with extensions to force evaluations?**

Comment: +1. Welcome to our site! Thanks for asking your question here, and we hope to see much more of you!!!  The answer by ProfM is only for BSE. I think this question might be better off being two separate questions, one for TDDFT and one for BSE. We can see what the community feels.

Comment: I agree with Nike. I think if you split the question in two and provide a link between the two, you will get better answers that more specifically address each method (not to say that ProfM hasn't already provided a great answer for BSE). Since this question already has a BSE answer, I would suggest cutting TDDFT from this question and making a new post for that.

Comment: About the structure of this question, there is now a discussion on Meta: https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/194/5

Comment: Thanks. I have split the questions in two parts. The TDDFT part is here https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/2226/is-there-a-software-that-has-implemented-forces-of-tddft-calculations-for-solids.

Comment: ABINIT, Yambo and exciting should have BSE. I'm not sure if they have it implemented for the property you want, but they may be a good place to start (or someone with more knowledge of these codes can step in and clarify).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not aware of any public codes that have a force implementation for excited state calculations using the Bethe-Salpeter equation (happy to be corrected on this front). However, the methodology to do this was published some time ago by Ismail-Beige and Louie in this [paper](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.90.076401), where they also have an in-house implementation that they use to validate the methodology by studying:

> photoexcited carbon dioxide and ammonia molecules, and the calculations accurately describe the excitation energies and photoinduced structural deformations

Comment: +1. For the fast answer. Maybe this can become HNQ. I suppose the user can get the code from the authors of that paper if they need to do force with BSE.